# Escape dollar sign in JavaScript template literals (template strings)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I am using the new template literals (template strings) syntax of JavaScript ES6 [Docs Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and I am not quite sure how to escape the dollar sign that is used to break the string to add a parameter.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
var response = `I consent to my credit card being charged in the amount of
                 $ ${ total } for the purchase of ${ item.title } and any
                 applicable sales tax.`
```

that works fine... but I would really prefer to not have that space `$ ${title}`

that leaves the end result looking like :

> ... in the amount of $ 25.99 for the purchase...

I would really rather prefer

> ... in the amount of $25.99 for the purchase ...

I guess that is ok, or obviously I could use the old way that still works, but it would be nice to know how to fix this.  I linked to the Mozilla docs , and I can't find anything in there about it, hopefully someone has an idea how to fix this

Comment: `$${title}` not working?

Comment: nope , tried that , the string doesn't break if you put $$

Comment: Working for me in Firefox 48.

Comment: what's your setup/transpiler/environment? it works for me on Chrome and node

Comment: how about `\$${title}`

Comment: it was a problem with visual studios and resharper not liking it , it works , the IDE just won't allow it , my bad

Comment: This actually may help future users , I confirmed this really is not working right with the intellisence in Visual Studios , it is definitely showing a syntax error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var response = `I consent to my credit card being charged in the amount of
                 $${ total } for the purchase of ${ item.title } and any
                 applicable sales tax.`
```

Comment: I'll undo the downvote if I can get it to work , it's not workign in chrome browser with iis express .net

Comment: it was a visual studios and resharper mess up  sorry

Comment: @ScottSelby check updated answer. Both working on Chrome.

Comment: it was a problem with Visual Studios not liking , I was just going to delete question , but I'll leave it so you can get some points , i'll accept when it lets me

Comment: `\ ` slash is redundant there.

Comment: @zerkms - he only added the slash because I incorrectly told him it wasn't working,  like I said I was going to delete this question because it will do no benifit to future users , but I'll let you keep the points

Comment: Visual Studios has Update 3 as of June 30 '16 and now it understands the ES6 string interpolation

Comment: I found one interesting video explaining ES6 template literals here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asRu9MPojFE

Answer (score 49):

The only case where `$` does not produce the literal `$` is before a `{`, otherwise you do not need to escape it.

```
var response = `You have $${money}`
```

does work therefore. In case you need to escape anything, the backslash `\` is the escape character in template strings as well, so (while unnecessary) the following works as well:

```
var response = `You have \$${money}`
```

Comment: it was a problem with my local evironment which was stopping it from compiling and even getting to the browser  , but you are right , it works fine in the browser

Answer (score 15):

Putting a backslash in front of the dollar sign was the first thing that comes to my mind and it works:

```
\${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
var response = `You have \$\{money}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
<v-btn :href="mail">
   Send Mail
</v-btn>
```

```
const mail = 'mailto:berkaynayman4@gmail.com'
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30949907)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (Tested using Node.js)

```js
`$\${money}`
```

`\$` is the escape character for `$` 
Edit: I misunderstood the question, you can actually insert `$` as long as it isn't followed by braces.