# How To escape JS template Literals ECMA 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I am making a HTML Template generator, and I am using the backticks to return HTML, to generate a static HTML File.

I want the generated file to have the use of using template literals
I have tried escaping the middle two ticks which works but how would I escape ${x}?

***A user has marked this as a duplicate, and it has absolutely nothing to do with the duplicate question, the other question is about escaping back ticks, I want to know how to escape the variables inside the backticks***

```
    return `const func = x => `I am ${x}` `
```

Comment: Use a \: `\`const func = x => \\`I am ${x}\\` \``

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043686/escape-dollar-sign-in-es6-string-literal

Comment: thanks, but then the ${x} is still active, I want that as a string, to save&write a JS script, not actual execute a JS script. I guess I could write it as a JS file, and not have node write the js file

Comment: Just escape the `$` too.

Comment: `\`const func = x => \\`I am \${x}\\` \``

Comment: wow thats pretty neat, I didn't think templates could be nested like that